# Is the concept/phenomenon of eka santha grahi mentioned in scriptures?

Tags: scripture

In general, people who can understand any concept from any branch of knowledge after listening or reading or analyzing **a single** time are called eka santha grahi.

Is there any mention or details of the eka santha grahi(s) found in scriptures?

Comment: Not found in Sanskrit dictionary. There is something called [ekāntagrāhin](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/ek%C4%81ntagr%C4%81hin/45214/1) but it has a different meaning altogether ('comprehending partially').